# Looking for (less sci-fi or fantasy but certainly phantasmagoric) novel encountered many years ago

Tags: story-identification, novel

Now this is going to be really tough since I remember very little about the novel, but maybe...

The novel is something between political satire and psychological/psychedelic/psychiatric thriller, similar in spirit to movies like [The Ruling Class](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069198/) or rather [Todo Modo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075335/). The reason I seek analogies in movies rather than in literature is that (a) the style was so vivid and picturesque that I still have the impression of having actually seen it as a movie rather than having read it in text and (b) I can't really think of any novel with similar developments.

The whole plot took place in some secret underground offices, where government officials were secretly meeting for various hidden activities ranging from deciding state matters of utter importance to various secret forms of entertainment. Actually that secret place was the main character, and maybe even its name was present in the title, although again maybe not. The characters, mostly ministers, parliament members, maybe some occasional very high profile prostitutes, were behaving extravagantly, much attention was given to their unusual but strict dress-code - some satin-like black cloaks, ties, ...

The plot was outstandingly dynamic, gradually becoming more and more bizarre and paranoid, towards the end feverishly so, there were astonishing revelations which were never confirmed and might actually be just results of serious mental disorder of either storyteller or of the very universe. This was the main characteristic of the novel for me, I've never seen such incredible acceleration of the plot and such deep intermingling of reality with insane delusions.

I did read it around early eighties, or maybe mid-eighties, in Russian translation, in the Soviet magazine Иностранная Литература (Foreign Literature).

The author was either Italian or English/American, I don't remember for sure.

I'm afraid that's all I can remember. Maybe asking this question here stimulates my memory and I can come up with more details, in that case of course I will add them here.

Comment: Your description as it currently stands has zero sci-fi, zero fantasy and even zero phantasmagoric elements and will be flagged as off-topic. Can you think of any additional details that would help make this question a good fit for this site?

Comment: You remember that there were astonishing revelations yet cannot remember any detail about any of those revelations? That does not sound that astonishing to me...

Comment: @S. Fruggiero: Not all science fiction involves technology; not all fantasy involves dragons and elves.

Comment: @JoeL. I agree completely, that does not change the fact that NO elements of either genre is described here. As it stands, the novel appears to be a standard Thriller. Without additional information from the OP, it will remain as such.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about a work of Science Fiction or Fantasy.

Comment: @S. Fruggiero: I think a secret society controlling society from hidden underground offices sounds like a good fit for the SFF genre.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero Acknowledging your concerns, let me still remark that for example Gogol's "Nose" is designated by himself as a fantasy story (фантастический рассказ), and there are many other similar examples on the borderline of fantasy and more heavy-weight kind of fiction.

Comment: @SJuan76 It is very disappointing, I agree. But it was many years ago, and too many things happened in between, sorry.

Comment: In some ways your question reminds me of Chesterton's *The Man Who Was Thursday* but there are too many differences. According to my recollection (maybe faulty as it was many years ago I read it), the action in "Thursday" is not all underground or all in one place, on the contrary there is a lot of travel.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero What is your non-fantastic interpretation of "serious mental disorder . . . of the very universe"?

Comment: @user14111 Yes thanks for your interest, the atmosphere was indeed very much like Chesterton's in Thursday or some of the best Father Brown stories, but there was one crucial difference - Chesterton's crescendo heads towards mind-shaking resolution, while that novel headed towards increasingly hopeless insanity. And this is also a very good example - Chesterton's are among the best fantasy writings I've ever seen!

Comment: May I recommend the [literature.se] SE (a newer site, which didn't exist when you posted this question) for ID questions about written stories which are not sci-fi or fantasy? Or let's say which are not accepted as sci-fi or fantasy on this site, since this case seems somewhat arguable. I'd migrate your question to Literature if it wasn't too old to be migrated. As it is, you can re-ask over there, if you're still looking for this; I think the Literature community would be interested :-)